# How to containerize workflow which consists of several python scripts and softwares?

Tags: python, docker, containers, workflow

A bioinformatics protocol was developed and we would like to dockerize it to make its usage easier for others. It consists of 2 softwares and several python scripts to prepare and parse data. Locally, we run these modules on a cluster as several dependent jobs (some requiring high resources) with a wrapper script, like this:

1. parsing input data (python)
2. running a few 10-100 jobs on a cluster (each having a piece of the output of step 1). Every step's job depends on the previous one finishing, involving:
   a) compiled C++ software on each piece from 1
   b) a parsing python script on each piece from 2a
   c) an other, resource-intensive compiled C++ software; which uses mpirun to distribute all the output of 2b
3. finalizing results (python script) on all results from step 2

The dockerized version does not necessarily needs to be organized in the same manner, but at least 2c needs to be distributed with mpirun because users will run it on a cluster.

How could I organize this? Have X different containers in a workflow? Any other possible solution that does not involve multiple containers?

Thank you!

ps. I hope I described it clearly enough but can further clarify if needed

Answer (score 1):

I think in your project it is important to differentiate docker images and docker container.

In a docker image, you will package your code and the dependencies to make it work. The first question is, should all your code be in the same image : you have python scripts, c++ software, so it could make sense to have several images, each capable to run one job of your process.

A docker container is a running instance of a docker image. So if you decided to have several images, you will have several docker containers running during your process. If you decide to have only one image, then you can decide to run everything in one container, by running your wrapper script in the container. Or you could have a new wrapper script instantiating docker containers for each step. This could be interesting as you seem to use different hardware depending on the step.

I can't give specifics about mpirun as I'm not familiar with it